# Use DbContext in ActionFilter Middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

I want to use a `DbContext` in my ActionFilter Middleware. Is it possible?

```
public class VerifyProfile : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        using (var context = new SamuraiDbContext())
        {
            var user = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            if (context.Profiles.SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.IdentityName == user).Result == null)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/admin/setup");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this code `using (var context = new SamuraiDbContext())` requires to pass options. Should I again pass `DbContextOptionsBuilder()` here or is there any other way?

I want to have `[VerifyProfile]` attribute in my controllers method. Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Instead of trying to create a new instance of `SamuraiDbContext` yourself, use [Dependency Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.0#dependency-injection) in your Filter. To achieve this, you need to do three things:

1. Add a constructor to `VerifyProfile` with a parameter of type `SamuraiDbContext` and store it as a field:

   ```
   private readonly SamuraiDbContext dbContext;

   public VerifyProfile(SamuraiDbContext dbContext)
   {
       this.dbContext = dbContext;
   }
   ```
2. Add `VerifyProfile` to the DI container:

   ```
   services.AddScoped<VerifyProfile>();
   ```
3. Use `ServiceFilter` to take care of connecting your filter to the DI container:

   ```
   [ServiceFilter(typeof(VerifyProfile))]
   public IActionResult YourAction()
       ...
   ```

You can apply the `ServiceFilter` attribute at the action level, as shown, or at the controller level. You can also apply it globally. To do that, replace step 3 above with the following:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add<VerifyProfile>();
});
```

As an additional resource, [this blog post](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/dependency-injection-in-action-filters-in-asp.net-core) has a good write up of some of the other options.